# Showing a button on a selected datagridrow

Tags: wpf, button, datagrid, visibility, selected

I have a datagrid with a number ow rows. Every row has as DeleteRow-button. Only the row that is selected should have this button visible. As I see it there may be at least two solutions:

a) binding the Visibility-property of the button to the IsSelected-property of the containing DatGridRow

or

b) using a trigger in the button to only be visible when the containing row is selected.

This is the code I have for option b, which isn't working:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Width="50">
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Button Content="X" Tag="{Binding}" Click="DeletRow_Click" Visibility="Hidden">
            <Button.Style>
                <Style x:Name="ButtonVisibility">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}},Path=IsSelected}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property= "Button.Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Button.Style>
        </Button>
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```

It's probably really easy but I've been staring so much it's blinding me now :S

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It doesn't work because of [Dependency Property Value Precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230.aspx#listing). You can't change a local value within a `Style`. Move `Visibility.Hidden` into `Style` and it will work.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Button Content="X" Tag="{Binding}" Click="DeletRow_Click">
            <Button.Style>
                <Style x:Name="ButtonVisibility">
                    <Setter Property="Button.Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}, Path=IsSelected}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Button.Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Button.Style>
        </Button>
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the converter `BooleanToVisibiltyConverter` provided by WPF to toggle the visibility for your button -

```
<DataGrid>
            <DataGrid.Resources>
                <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter"/>
            </DataGrid.Resources>
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="50">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Button Content="X" Tag="{Binding}"
                                    Visibility="{Binding IsSelected, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter},
                                                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGridRow}}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I try to avoid converters if a thing can be done in another way. Maybe this will come in handy for something else though.

Comment: Yeah i too avoid writing converters but here i am not writing one. Using some default converters provided by WPF itself. :)